# How to properly set prop type in React using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react component called LinkButton, and it has the following props. I've been having issues with correctly setting the prop type of the link prop.

```
interface IProps {
  text?: string;
  onClick?: (e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => void;
  type?: ButtonType;
  link: string | {
    pathname: string;
    state: { from: string};
    hash: string;
  };
  target?: React.HTMLAttributeAnchorTarget;
  useAnchorTag?: boolean;
}
```

Below is how the link prop is used. Part of the difficulty in setting the type is that, it's used for both the html href attribute and react-router-dom Link.

```
   if (!useAnchorTag) return <Link to={link}>{text}</Link>;
    return <a. href={link}>
      {text}
    </a>;
```

The current type of the link prop is causing the following errors for the a href attribute.

```
Type 'string | { pathname: string; state: { from: string; }; hash: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
```

I found that undefined is being derived from the property itself

```
index.d.ts(2012, 9): The expected type comes from property 'href' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>
(JSX attribute) AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>.href?: string | undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` expects a `string` (or undefined) but your type says it's either `string` or your "path" object. So that is not compatible. If you want to have a type that works for both `href` and `Link` that type must only be `string`, because that is the only type that is accepted by both properties.

Comment: Oh. I don't think that will be possible for my case, because i want react-router-link to take a string or object.

Comment: You specify a type that can either be string OR your object. BUT: the `href` ONLY accepts strings. So it might be that at runtime your property is of your "path" type (and not a string). That wouldn't work with `href` and so you're getting an error here. You *could* check if your property is a string at runtime (`typeof link==='string'`) and then render the `a` with `href`. Then typescript knows that a runtime your property is always a string. Not sure if that helps in that context here, just for clarification)